# Two Tables with different purpose but same attributes / fields

Tags: database, database-design

I am working on a school management system which has two types of entities.

```
User
-----
UserId
UserType
Name
ContactNumber
Address
```

which holds all the students/ teacher for whose attendance is marked.

The other table is

```
ContactDetails
----
ContactId
Name
ContactNumber
Address
```

ContactDetails strores the information of  parents and relatives of the Users (via Mapping tables having many to many mappings) and their attendance is not marked.

I already have a aspnetUsers table in which all the credentials are stored.

The change now is that parents(not relatives) who are contacts need to log in to the system and update data.

there are two approaches for it.

1. Create a Usertype=Parent, drop table contacts and remap all relationships.
   Logging in system would only look into the user table for getting details after authentication.
2. Create a Role of a Parent in aspNetRoles and when the role= parent then look in User or Contacts depending upon the role for information.

Do two different entities having different purpose but same fields need to be need to be in different tables ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The similar attributes should be a hint. What you've got is one entity set in different roles. Can the same person be both a teacher and a parent? Can a student later become a teacher or parent?

Many systems start out handling various categories of people as different entity sets, which ends up causing duplication of work when the same changes need to be applied and the same queries run on multiple tables. Unifying distinct entity sets into one supertype after a database is populated is at least a time-consuming task, and can be difficult. It's much better if these generalizations can be built-in from the start.

I suggest something like the following:

```
Persons (PersonId PK, Name, ContactNumber, Address)
Users (PersonId PK/FK, Username, PasswordHash)
Students (PersonId PK/FK, ...)
Parents (PersonId PK/FK, ...)
Relatives (PersonId PK/FK, ...)
Teachers (PersonId PK/FK, ...)
```

This way, personal information for all people are stored in one place, and role-specific information for a person can be recorded in any of the relevant subtype tables.